# Cannot assign value of type while passing an object

Tags: ios, swift

Modal class

```
class Trip: NSObject {

    var tripTitle: String
    var tripSummary: String

   static var trips = [Trip]()

    init(tripTitle: String, tripSummary: String) {
        self.tripTitle = tripTitle
        self.tripSummary = tripSummary

    }

   class func addTrip(tripTitle: String, tripSummary: String){

            let t = Trip(tripTitle: tripTitle, tripSummary: tripSummary)

           trips.append(t)
        }

}
```

In Controller

```
@IBAction func previewButtomPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let tripTitle = tripTitleTxt.text!
        let tripSummary = tripSummaryTxt.text!



        Trip.addTrip(tripTitle, tripSummary: tripSummary)



}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowTripPreviewTableViewController" {


        let tripPreviewTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TripPreviewTableViewController
         tripPreviewTableViewController.trip = Trip //here I am getting an error
    }
}
```

**error**

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Trip.Type' to type 'Trip'
```

**tripPreviewTableViewController**

```
var trip : Trip!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you can't assign a Class type to a variable which represents an instance of that class, since the Class is not an instance.

However, if your class represents a trip, why does this class:

- have a static class variable to hold an array of trips?
- have a class method that creates a new trip and appends it to the array of trips?

If your class is meant to represent a single trip, it should only encapsulate properties and methods that refer to an instance's trip.

It seems like you're trying to also misuse the class to serve as a "global" model which happens to hold an array of trips. If you want to keep track of a collection of trips, it would make your code easier (for you and others) to understand and maintain, if you stored that array of trips outside the `Trip` class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the type of your `tripPreviewTableViewController.trip` but it makes more sense for me to do:

`tripPreviewTableViewController.trip = Trip.trips`

**Edit**

Two ways to do it:

1) You change the type of `tripPreviewTableViewController.trip` to `[Trip]?`. When you assign the value you can do `tripPreviewTableViewController.trip = Trip.trips`

2) You can access `Trip` class inside your `tripPreviewTableViewController`.

Comment: the type is this var trip : Trip! ..I wrote it in the question

Comment: sorry didn't get you.. you mean to say I should declare a variable in this controller tripPreviewTableViewController like this

var [trip] : Trip!

Answer (score 2):

In your case, as `trips` is an **static variable**, you do **NOT** need to pass anything via segue.

Just ask for `Trip.trips` when you needed in your destination view (`TripPreviewTableViewController`)